# Why does adding keyword function before makeSquare(){...} give me parsing error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
makeSquare(i){
         return (<Square/>);
    }


    render(){
        return(

        <div class="Board">

        <br/>
                    <div id="first-line">
                        {this.makeSquare(0)}
                    </div>
        </div>
}
```

It works like this but if makeSquare is a function, then why can i not add the function keyword before it.

Comment: Is this inside a class? If so, that would be why, as class methods are not declared as just `function makeSquare(i) {` for instance. (You could do something like `this.makeSquare = function(i) {` if you wanted to, though.)

Answer (score 1):

No need to use function keyword if you are defining function inside class, more refer- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes